# d3js in vue as external script [ d3 is not defined ]

Tags: html, vue.js, d3.js

**I tried to add script d3js in vue**

**but there's a problem said that d3 is not defined eror is like this**

> ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
> at VueComponent.drawRect (AddMatchingComp.vue?./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0:264)
> at VueComponent.mounted (AddMatchingComp.vue?./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0:283)
> at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.esm.js:1862)
> at callHook (vue.esm.js:4216)
> at Object.insert (vue.esm.js:3145)
> at invokeInsertHook (vue.esm.js:6341)
> at Vue.patch [as **patch**] (vue.esm.js:6560)
> at Vue._update (vue.esm.js:3945)
> at Vue.updateComponent (vue.esm.js:4063)
> at Watcher.get (vue.esm.js:4476)

is there anything wrong with my code , why d3 is not defined even i have add the script in mounted

here is my code :

```html
<template>
<div>
    <div id="svgHere">

    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    name:"testD3",
    props:{
      
    },
    components: {
        
    },
    data(){
        return{
          
    },
    methods:{  
       
    },
    mounted(){
        let d3Script = document.createElement('script')
        d3Script.setAttribute('type', "text/javascript");
        d3Script.setAttribute('src', 'https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js')
        document.head.appendChild(d3Script) 

        var dataArray = [2,13,15,20]
        var svg = d3.select("#svgHere").append("svg").attr("width", '100%').attr("height", '100%');
        svg.selectAll('rect').data(dataArray).enter().append('rect')
            .attr('height', function(d,i){return d*10})
            .attr('width','70')
            .attr('fill','darkred')
            .attr('x',function(d,i){return 80*i}) 
            .attr('y',function(d,i){return 350*(d*10)});
    },
    created(){
     
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: In mounted you're creating a script tag and setting it to load d3, but you're not waiting for it to actually load. If you do it that way, you have to place a trigger on the script's `onload` and run the d3 related functionality after the onload. Or you could simply `import` d3 in your component (from `node_modules/` => run `npm i d3` first). Vue loader will make sure it's loaded before the component is mounted and then you don't have to worry about it, as suggested in Boussadjra's answer.

Comment: oh i see ,thanks for the explanation sir @tao i would do the npm i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import it as follows :

```
<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";
export default{
 name:"testD3",
    props:{
      
    },
 ...
```